# Use TIMESTAMP in Firebase Security Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Is there a way to use Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP or new Date().getTime() in firebase security rules to check against a timestamp value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the '[now](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rule-expressions/now.html)' variable.  E.g.:

```
// Ensure data being written is in the future.
".write": "newData.val() >= now"
```